Template produces "1" at the end of a tabbing environment - I can't find out why
I am currently trying to make a very simple recipe template. My workflow is: Markdown -> Pandoc (LaTex — Lualatex Engine) -> PDF.
Everything works, but I can't figure out why there are 1 at the end of each Zutat/Ingridient.

The recipe.tex template file:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\newcommand\mreplace[1]{%
    \directlua{ 
        ing = "#1"
        tex.print(ing:gsub(",","\\>")) 
    }
}

\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}

$if(title)$
\title{$title$$if(thanks)$\thanks{$thanks$}$endif$}
$endif$
$if(subtitle)$
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\subtitle}[1]{% add subtitle to \maketitle
  \apptocmd{\@title}{\par {\large #1 \par}}{}{}
}
\makeatother
\subtitle{$subtitle$}
$endif$
\author{$for(author)$$author$$sep$ \and $endfor$}
\date{$date$}

\begin{document}
$if(title)$
    \chapter*{$title$}
$if(abstract)$
  \begin{abstract}
  $abstract$
  \end{abstract}
$endif$
$endif$
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tabbing}
        \textbf{Menge}\hspace{1cm}\= \textbf{Zutat} \\
        $for(ingridients)$
            \mreplace{$ingridients$}\\
        $endfor$
    \end{tabbing}    
\end{minipage}% This must go next to `\end{minipage}`
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \textbf{Anweisung(en)}
    $body$
\end{minipage}
\end{document}

The markdown file:
---
title: Balsamicomarinade
ingridients:
    - 3 El, Olivenöl
    - 1 El, Aceto Balsamic Essig
    - 1-2 El, Aceto Balsamic Creme
    - 1 EL, Sojasauce
    - 1 Spritz, Worchestersauce
    - 1 Spritz, Citronensaft
    - 2 Tl, Zucker
    - 1 Tl, Senf
    - 1/2 El, Ketchup
    - Etwas, Rosmarin
    - Etwas, Salz
    - Etwas, Pfeffer
    - Etwas, Knoblauchpulver
tag: recipe
---

 1. Zutaten in einen 2.5l wieder verschliessbaren Gefrierbeutel geben
 2. Kräftig massieren bis eine gleichmässige dicke Masse entsteht
 3. Fleisch beigeben und im Kühlschrank lagern für ca. 1-2 Stunden

The command I use to convert is:
docker run --rm -v .:/data pandoc/extra chicken-marinade.md -o chicken-marinade.pdf --template recipe.tex --pdf-engine=lualatex

Which produces the following LaTex code:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\newcommand\mreplace[1]{%
    \directlua{ 
        ing = "#1"
        tex.print(ing:gsub(",","\\>")) 
    }
}

\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}

\title{Balsamicomarinade}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    \chapter*{Balsamicomarinade}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tabbing}
        \textbf{Menge}\hspace{1cm}\= \textbf{Zutat} \\
                    \mreplace{3 El, Olivenöl}\\
                    \mreplace{1 El, Aceto Balsamic Essig}\\
                    \mreplace{1-2 El, Aceto Balsamic Creme}\\
                    \mreplace{1 EL, Sojasauce}\\
                    \mreplace{1 Spritz, Worchestersauce}\\
                    \mreplace{1 Spritz, Citronensaft}\\
                    \mreplace{2 Tl, Zucker}\\
                    \mreplace{1 Tl, Senf}\\
                    \mreplace{1/2 El, Ketchup}\\
                    \mreplace{Etwas, Rosmarin}\\
                    \mreplace{Etwas, Salz}\\
                    \mreplace{Etwas, Pfeffer}\\
                    \mreplace{Etwas, Knoblauchpulver}\\
            \end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}% This must go next to `\end{minipage}`
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \textbf{Anweisung(en)}
    <ol type="1">
    <li>Zutaten in einen 2.5l wieder verschliessbaren Gefrierbeutel
    geben</li>
    <li>Kräftig massieren bis eine gleichmässige dicke Masse
    entsteht</li>
    <li>Fleisch beigeben und im Kühlschrank lagern für ca. 1-2
    Stunden</li>
    </ol>
\end{minipage}
\end{document}


PS the recipe pretty good :)

Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us the resulting TeX code?

I have added the resulting Latex. Thanks for taking a look

I don't get the output you show I get this with html <ol markup in the third column

The string.gsub() Lua function returns two values: a modified string and the number of modifications done. If you use it directly in tex.print() then both values are printed. Try this:
\def\mreplace#1{%
    \directlua{ 
        ing = "#1"
        out = string.gsub(ing,",","\\>")
        tex.print(out)
    }
}


That was it!! Thanks so much, sorry for posting, what is bascially a lua question, in the Tex section!
